# Using javascript to write a box API

Tags: box-api

I'm using javascript to write box api i found out the following link:
http://developers.blog.box.com/2011/09/28/using-the-box-api-with-javascript/
which explain how to do it, 
 i wrote:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%20%3D%20'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.box.net%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Frest%3Faction%3Dget_ticket%26api_key%3D" + api_key + "'&amp;format=json&amp;diagnostics=true",

function (response) {


    window.ticket = response.query.results.response.ticket;

    window.location.href = 'https://m.box.net/api/1.0/auth/' + ticket;
```

but i get "400 bad request...
why?

Answer (score 0):

We don't officially support YQL. Our recommendation is to use our API directly: developers.box.com